# Firebase Cloud FunctionsでPuppeteerで絵文字のスクリーンショットが文字化けする

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, puppeteer

FirebaseのCloud Functionsで、Puppeteerを使用して絵文字入りのスクリーンショットを撮ろうとしているのですが、絵文字が文字化けしてしまいます。

CloudFunctionsのPuppeteerが絵文字フォントを読み込んでいないのが原因のようなので、@font-faceで絵文字フォントを指定しようとしているのですが、うまくいきません。

Cloud Functionsのコードは以下の通りです。
(以下のscreenshot()関数をCloudFunctionsのHTTPS関数内から呼び出しています。)

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
const storage = admin.storage();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function screenshot() {
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36');
      await page.evaluate(() => {
        const style = document.createElement('style')
        style.textContent = `
        @font-face {
          font-family: "emoji";
          src:local("Noto Color Emoji"),
              url("./NotoColorEmoji.ttf");
        };
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Noto Sans JP';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 400;
            src: local("Noto Sans CJK JP"),
              url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/notosansjp/v5/NotoSansJP-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
              url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/notosansjp/v5/NotoSansJP-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
              url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/notosansjp/v5/NotoSansJP-Regular.otf) format('opentype');
        };
        body, svg{ font-family: "Noto Sans JP", "emoji", sans-serif; };`
        document.head.appendChild(style);
        document.body.style.fontFamily = "'Noto Sans JP', 'emoji' , sans-serif";
      })
      await page.waitFor(5000); // waiting time to load font
      await page.goto("https://getemoji.com/"); //絵文字入りのサイトに移動
      await page.screenshot({
        path: '/tmp/screenshot.png',
        omitBackground: true,
      })
      .then(() => {
        // スクリーンショットをstorageにアップロード
        storage.bucket('bucketName').upload('/tmp/screenshot.png')
        .then(() => {
          console.log("success");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    })();
}
```

上記の結果のスクリーンショットは以下のようになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

解決策のわかる方いましたらアドバイスいただけると幸いです。

Comment: 試していないためコメントに記載します。絵文字が化けるのはfontが対応していからと思われます。フォントを導入する方法を検索したところ →が出たので試してみてはいかがでしょうか。  https://qiita.com/zyyx-matsushita/items/c33f79e33f242395019e#%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り原因はフォントの読み込みにあると思うのですが、Cloud Functionsの環境でフォントをうまく読み込む方法がまだ見つけられていません。記事はAWS版なのでCloud Functionsでも別方法でできないか試してみます。

Comment: これかもしれませんね。[PuppeteerによるヘッドレスChromeの使い方 evaluate](https://iwb.jp/puppeteer-headless-chrome-evaluate/)、[goto後にwaitForNavigationは意味がない](https://iwb.jp/puppeteer-headless-chrome-evaluate/#gotowaitForNavigation)、`この場合はgotoにwaitUntilのoptionを追加する。`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。waitUntilオプション試してみましたが駄目でした。ページロードは問題ないようです。やはりフォントの読み込みに問題があるようですが、まだ原因は見つけられていません。

Comment: 次に試すとしたらこれでしょうか。[Chrome拡張機能 Puppeteer Recorderの自動操作の使い方と注意点](https://iwb.jp/chrome-puppeteer-recorder-how-to-use/)、[{headless: false, slowMo: 100}を指定](https://iwb.jp/chrome-puppeteer-recorder-how-to-use/#headless_false_slowMo_100)